# What BarChart Option controls Joined line thickness?

Tags: graphics

Is there a named option that controls the thickness of the line segments that appear in `BarChart` with options `ChartLayout -> "Stacked"`, `Joined->True`? It is not `EdgeForm`, since `ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[None]` is the value set in the following example:

[image]

It's unclear what `Directive` can be passed. Changing `Thickness` value in `ChartBaseStyle -> {Thickness[0.0001], EdgeForm[None]}` has no effect for example.

Comment: Please include code for easy testing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I'll try do refactor the code, but as it is it's mixed in with data transforms on external data sets, it would be a mess to include it all. You can probably generate a random matrix and just set the `Option` values mentioned in the post.

Comment: `BaseStyle -> Thick` etc. will do it.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, thank you that works. Will accept if you post as an answer. It's even possible to specify `Thickness` numerically: `BaseStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.001]]`. However the `Color` *disappears*.. . curious why this `Option` is segregated in BaseStyle, not in ChartBaseStyle`

Comment: Actually I commented before testing -- always a bad move. `BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5]` works but messes up ticks. So you might have to explicitly specify a tick style to overcome that.

Comment: Actually not the ticks, the "divider lines" between groups of data that look like ticks are what is being messed up. I am pretty sure you can control those but off hand do not know the method. I need to go but maybe someone else can provide an answer that doesn't break something else!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following suggestions from Mike Honeychurch,

```
 BarChart[{Range[1, 3], Range[6, 8], Range[4, 6]}, Joined -> True, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], 
 Ticks -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image: stacked]

Comment: Ok if you're going to blatantly take Honeychurch's votes...

Comment: @alancalvitti I don't receive votes for a community wiki.

Comment: ok, didn't realize - was joken anyway

Comment: Just returning to this today over breakfast and would still be nice to be able to retain the tick marks but to exclude them from the effects applied to the joined line. For some reason `TicksStyle` is not working for these x axis tick marks (group divider ticks -- whatever they are called). It might be something Brett Champion can help with.

Comment: Yes. I used `None` because I didn't see the point of the ticks. But now that you mention it, it may be worth taking a look at Absolute Options.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I can't figure out how the x ticks get placed.  `Ticks -> {{}, Automatic}` leaves no ticks; `Ticks -> {{1,2,3}, Automatic}` leaves regular sized ticks. The ones that are used to separate the bars are not acknowledged by `AbsoluteOptions[%,Ticks]`.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I found similar when I had a look at this earlier this morning. It seems inconsistent. If a setting of `None` removes these tick marks you would expect to be able to control the thickness (and colour etc.) with `TicksStyle`.

Comment: Exactly the source of my puzzlement. It's as if BarChart slips some x ticks into the chart through the back door.